# Autonumbering using ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, web-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I work for a water utility division and we are using ArcMap 10.1 with attribute assistant. I used the AutoNumber method to auto increment and populate a field with the next highest integer. Unfortunately this method does not seem to work in ESRI Web AppBuilder. 
Anytime I edit my layer and create new fields using the Editor widget provided by Web AppBuilder, the value of the AutoNumber field is set as 0. However, it works perfectly through the Editor session in ArcMap.
Is there a way to make it work through the Web AppBuilder ? Or is there another option to auto populate a field when using Web AppBuilder and considering daily updates ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "attribute assistant ". It sounds like an ESRI addin for ArcGIS Desktop. Is this the case? If so it won't work with map services or AppBuilder web apps since ArcGIS Server map services won't use an ArcGIS Desktop edit session. There are a couple of other options but neither is straightforward. If you can confirm what exactly "attribute assistant " is then I can discuss the alternatives I know of for Map Services.

Comment: @Dowlers is right. I don't think the logic of attribute assistant has been ported into a SOE extension for Server.  
http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/tools/